# Create a static grid in android

Tags: java, android, gridview, grid

I would like to create a static grid 100x100 in my app. 
This grid can be scrolled in vertical and horizontal. 
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you guys

Comment: Have you looked at using GridView? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: But, exit any way to set a static raw?